# Having multiple Twitter instances with twitter4j library.

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, access-token, twitter4j

I need to be able to make different `Twitter` instances with **same consumer key and secret but different user level access tokens**.

I have already obtained the access tokens for 10 users based on consumer credentials of my app by using standard Twitter OAuth Sign In protocol. Now, I want to create a list of Twitter Instances each initialized with a separate `Accesstoken`. However, I'm not able to do this.

My leading cause of confusion is, that, I don't understand how `Twitter4j` instantiates Twitter instances. I don't understand the difference between `TwitterFactory.getSingleton()` method and `TwitterFactory().getInstance()` method.

I also don't understand if AccessTokens can work independently without supplying consumer key and secret. Or do I need to provide Consumer key and secret while using Accesstokens.

If someone can explain in detail the design for my requirement it'll be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

In short, you may want code like this:

```
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory();
Twitter user1 = tf.getInstance(new AccessToken("XXX","XXX"));
Twitter user2 = tf.getInstance(new AccessToken("XXX","XXX"));
```

A Twitter instance can handle only one account.
To deal with multiple accounts, you need to instantiate multiple Twitter instances with TwitterFactory#getInstance(AccessToken);

Hard-coding consumer key/secret is not suggested and you may want to specify them in twitter4j.properties.
http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html#fileconfiguration

Comment: I want to have the same Twitter instance across the entire app; for some reason, after having that instance inside Application class, it crashes when I try to call it from a different activity. Do I need to store the access token and then use it later to get a new instance of Twitter? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Damn it a little bit more googling would have saved me 100 rep.

Let's be clear: there is a difference between `Twitter` and `TwitterStream` instances. `Twitter` instances can indeed have one consumer key+ secret and multiple OAuth tokens. That answers the question by the OP.

Now, for `Twitterstream` instances (that are needed to access the Twitter Streaming API), that's different. You can only have only **one TwitterStream ojbect running at a given time**, not several *even if they have different OAuth tokens*.

According to [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/14935),

> You'll be best served by sticking to the concept of "one account, one
>   application, one open connection" when connecting to the
>   stream.twitter.com endpoints. If there are other distinct applications
>   you plan to use with stream.twitter.com, I would strive to follow the
>   same 1:1:1 concept for it.
>
> You may find that at times stream.twitter.com lets you get away with
>   more open connections here or there, but that behavior shouldn't be
>   counted on.

I give the bounty to Yusuke Yamamoto since he provided the correct answer first, and do consider upvoting this one too if it clarifies things for you! ;-)

Comment: Also being the author of Twitter4J helps ;)