# Error on getting authorization URL more than once in Twitter4j

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I'm using Twitter4j to implement the authorization workflow on my webapp (user acesses a page, twitter asks permission, I receive the callback and generate the oauth access token).

My first problem was that if I called a method to get the Twitter sigleton:

```
Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(getClientId(), getClientSecret());
```

1) Since OAuthConsumer would already be defined I would get an exception. And I can't find how to ask the singleton if it already has the credentials defined. What's the best way? My solution was to save the singleton in a private member...

2) Now I want to generate an AuthorizationURL, so I need to ask Twitter singleton the OAuthRequestToken:

```
RequestToken oauthRequestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(getCallbackURL()); //FIXME
```

And this throws an exception:

```
401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
message - Invalid or expired token.
code - 89


Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
 http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=3cc69290 or
 http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=45a986a5
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[3cc69290-45a986a5], statusCode=401, message=Invalid or expired token., code=89, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.4}
 at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
 at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
 at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:86)
 at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:115)
 at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:92)
 at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:292)
 at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:287)
 (...)
```

> Note: the 'Relevant discussions' links are not working as expected I think...

In short:

1) How can I ask the singleton if it already has the credentials defined in order to 'setOAuthConsumer' doesn't throw an error ?

2) How to re-ask the singleton to generate a new authorizationURL for the user to access and authorize (again) ?

Also posted in the corresponding [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/twitter4j/ZrLIX2YT2n0/jUkkYxIbBQAJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've found is presented here:

```
Twitter instance = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
instance.setOAuthConsumer(getClientId(), getClientSecret());
RequestToken requestToken = new RequestToken(getOauthToken(),getOauthTokenSecret());
AccessToken oAuthAccessToken = instance.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, oauthVerifier);
```

`requestToken`and `oauthVerifier` are received as parameters in the callback. `getOauthToken()` and `getOauthTokenSecret()` retrieve the tokens retrieved by the library in the first step and that were saved in a cache (user -> tokens).

Inspired by this question/answers: [Having multiple Twitter instances with twitter4j library.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137037/having-multiple-twitter-instances-with-twitter4j-library)

Answer (score 2):

## 1) How can I ask the singleton if it already has the credentials defined in order to 'setOAuthConsumer' doesn't throw an error ?

There are a few ways that this can be done. You can set the oAuth consumer key and secret in a properties file named `twitter4j.properties` on your classpath. When you use the `TwitterFactory`, this is where the default properties come from.

If you want to set the values programmatically, the `TwitterFactory` also has a few overloaded constructors which allow this:

```
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
    Configuration configuration = builder.build();
    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
    Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
```

## 2) How to re-ask the singleton to generate a new authorizationURL for the user to access and authorize (again) ?

I assume that your requirement is to have the user authorize every time. If this is the case, this is handled via Twitters API. There are 2 oAuth endpoints `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate` and `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize`. The `authenticate` endpoint is the normal `Sign in with Twitter` functionality where the user will approve once and then automatically logged in every time after. The `authorize` endpoint will require authorization every time.

Using Twitter4j, these are separate methods that can be called on your `RequestToken`. You redirect to the appropriate URL based on your requirement.

Comment: I guess the first item may be another solution for my problem, but I have not tested it.
About the second item: I guess I really need another URL because of the nonce parameter and the signature field used to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks